# SCSS will not compile, SASS error, no .sass files

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

Using VueJS to build an application. Everything has gone pretty well, and much has been done already. Suddenly, this error is happening. I've rolled back as far as I can reasonably and still see this error - I do no know what could have changed in the configuration that would cause this to suddenly appear.

```
Invalid CSS after "/* banners */": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@mixin banner-red-t"
      in C:\Projects\MyTestVueProject\src\App.vue (line 1534, column 1)
```

The file in question with this error is `.scss` and starts like this:

```
/* banners */
@mixin banner-red-text{ 
    font-family:$font-family-primary;
    font-weight:$font-weight-regular;
    font-size:42px;
    color: $red;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

I have not a single .sass file in the entire project. Every component has  `lang="scss"`, style-resource-loader is set to `preProcessor: 'scss'` and every file involved has the .scss extension.

And yet, I get this error otherwise attributed to trying to compile SCSS as SASS everywhere else someone has asked.

I am using the node-sass and sass-loader packages, but these appear to be the correct packages to use for scss compilation.

```
"node-sass": "^4.12.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
```

Has anyone found another reason to see the above error, and hopefully how to fix it? Barring that, any pointers on what else to look at will be taken and used to expand this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another file, loaded immediately before this one in the style-resources-loader, was missing a `;` after its final declaration. When the files are pre-loaded it is causing the singular virtual chunk of scss to be malformed.

Leave it to me to figure it out 25 seconds after I posted the question.